# Integration of function using Hausdorff measure of Cantor Set

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, hausdorff-measure, fractal-analysis

I am learning geometry on fractal shapes, along with how fractional calculus can relate to said geometry. At the moment I am trying to understand integration over a Hausdorff measure.

According to Falconer's The Geometry of Fractal Sets, the middle-third Cantor set has a $\log_3 2$-Hausdorff measure of $1$. I would like to describe this relation as $\int_{C} 1 \; \mathrm{d}H^{s}(x)=1$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, and $s = \log_3 2$.

**My question is**: How would the integral $$\int_{C} (e^x + x)\; \mathrm{d}H^{s}(x)$$ be evaluated?

I'm not entirely sure where to begin in evaluating this, since this is new to me. I would appreciate resources as well, but I think an answer to this problem will give me the tools I need to evaluate other functions on other fractal sets.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Although I'm not a new member, I recognize I probably should have added more context. I've edited the post now. Thank you.

Comment: In order to give us some notion of what kind of answer you may or may not understand, would you mind to give us an example of an integral with respect to a Hausdorff measure you were able to do? Thank you! Edit: valuable resources are textbooks and professors knowing your background.

Comment: +Professor Vector So far, I have only integrated in respect to indicator functions or area, nothing involving algebraic expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend the paper [Evaluating Integrals Using Self-similarity](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/AMM/evaluatingintegrals.pdf) by Robert Strichartz. Since Hausdorff measure on the Cantor set happens to be a self-similar measure, the ideas in that paper are applicable. In that paper, we learn  that the basic properties of the integral yield a self-similar identity for integration over the Cantor set $C$ with Hausdorff measure $\mu$:

$$\int_C f(x) \, d\mu =  \frac{1}{2}\int_C f\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)d\mu + \frac{1}{2} \int_C f\left(\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}\right)d\mu.$$

We can use this to evaluate the second term in your integral exactly:

$$
\begin{align}
  \int_C x \, d\mu &= \frac{1}{2}\int_C \left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)d\mu + \frac{1}{2} \int_C \left(\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}\right)d\mu \\
 &= \frac{1}{6} \int_C x \, d\mu + \frac{1}{6} \int_C x \, d\mu + \frac{1}{3} \int_C 1 \, d\mu
\end{align}
$$

We can now solve for $\int_C x \, d\mu$ in terms of $\int_C 1 \, d\mu=1$ to get

$$\int_C x \, d\mu = \frac{1}{2}.$$

It's worth mentioning that this same technique can be applied to $\int_C x^n \, d\mu$ to derive a recursive technique to integrate $x^n$ for every integer $n$ and, therefore, any  polynomial.

Unfortunately,  I do not believe that the integrals of the transcental functions can be expressed  in closed form. They can be estimated numerically easily enough, though. For example, the picture below should convince you that

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(1+e^{2/9}+e^{2/3}+e^{8/9}\right) < \int_C e^x \, d\mu < \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt[9]{e}+\sqrt[3]{e}+e^{7/9}+e\right).$$

[image]

Taking that out to 20 iterations, I estimate that

$$1.75327920434 < \int_C e^x \, d\mu < 1.75327920485.$$

Comment: This is very nice! Could the transcendental function $e^x$ be evaluated through its Taylor series in this case (assuming additivity of course)? I'll try that out with the recursive polynomial theorem there.

Comment: I think you might be able express the exponential integral as a series using this technique but I don't think there's any reason to think that the resulting series would have a closed form.

Comment: Do you know of any good textbooks about integrating Hausdorff measures?

Comment: @JayZenvia I don't. I should also probably mention that the technique I outline is really specific to *self-similar measures*. It's really rather a coincidence that the Hausdorff measure is the same as the self-similar measure in this case. In particular, it's rare that the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of a self-similar set should be 1 and it can be quite hard to find that normalizing factor.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: This is a really good answer. In my expository answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037257/investigating-a-1-2-dimensional-sphere/4042618#4042618) I really wanted to compute a similar integral. But unfortunately I do not have enough knowledge about  Hausdorff measure to do so. It would be really nice, if you have some time to answer that question with an explicit computation, or at least an approximation.

Comment: @Bumblebee Thanks! I appreciate your vote of confidence. Honestly, though, I don't think that question is well-defined so I just left a comment to that effect.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I was able to determine that

$$\int_{C} \alpha^{\beta x} \mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 + \alpha^{\frac{2\beta}{3^n}}}{2}.$$